# Get the inverse of a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, join

I am using SQL Server 2005. I have three tables - Users, Groups, and GroupUsers. GroupUsers contains the two PKs for a many-to-many relationship.

I have a view to get all the user information for a group as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM GroupUsers JOIN Users ON GroupUsers.UserID = Users.UserId
```

I want to create the inverse of this view - I want a list of all of the users NOT attached to a specific group. The following query would accomplish this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID NOT IN 
    (SELECT UserID FROM GroupUsers WHERE GroupID=@GroupID)
```

However I don't want to have to specify the group, I want to know how to turn this into a view that joins the GroupID and then the UsersID and all the user info, but only for non-attached users.

I'm not sure how to do this, maybe something with the EXCEPT operator?

UPDATE:

I think this is my solution, unless someone comes up with something better:

```
SELECT 
   G.GroupId,
   U.*
FROM
   Groups G
CROSS JOIN
   Users U
WHERE
   U.UserId NOT IN 
     (
        SELECT 
           UserId
        FROM
           GroupUsers
        WHERE
           GroupId=G.GroupId
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you will have to do a cartersian result of users & groups and reduce the result derived from GroupUsers.

That will give you records of users which do not have any groups attached to it.
I apologize if I didn't understand the question correctly.

EDIT: Cartesian result will give you users * groups. You will have to subtract GroupUsers from it. I am sorry, I do not have SQL ready for it & can't try it out at this point.

Comment: You're right - I don't know why I didn't think of that. So this cross join/correlated subquery appears to work:

SELECT G.GroupId, U.* FROM Groups G CROSS JOIN Users U WHERE U.UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM ou_GroupUsers WHERE GroupId=G.GroupId)

Comment: If anyone knows of a better (more efficient) way to do this, please let me know. Thanks shahkalpesh.

Comment: I am not sure of performance but you could use NOT EXISTS. Also, if SQL supports EXCEPT - that should work as well.

Answer (score 42):

You can use a `left outer join` to grab all of the users, then, blow away any user where there's a group attached. The following query will give you just the list of users where there's no group to be had:

```
select
    u.*
from
    users u
    left outer join groupusers g on
        u.userid = g.userid
where
    g.userid is null
```

If you want to find all users not in a particular group:

```
select
    u.*
from
    users u
    left outer join groupusers g on
        u.userid = g.userid
        and g.groupid = @GroupID
where
    g.userid is null
```

This will *only* exclude the users in that particular group. Every other user will be returned. This is because the `groupid` condition was done in the `join` clause, which limits the rows joined, not returned, which is what the `where` clause does.

Comment: The first query works, but where my confusion lies is I want the view to have the GroupId that the user doesn't belong to. The GroupId would be null with an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure out how to get previous version to work via active record, got some of the way there but had to write an SQL in statement.  I believe this also accomplishes the same thing.

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID NOT IN 
(SELECT U.UserID FROM GroupUsers AS G, Users as U WHERE G.UserID <> U.UserID)
```

Couldn't test however this query in rails worked just fine:

```
# Gets Pre-Clients.  Has client information but no project attached
Contact.joins(:client).includes(:projects => :primary_contact).
where("contacts.id NOT IN (select contacts.id from contacts, 
projects where projects.primary_contact_id = contacts.id)")
```

Thanks for the post got me 90% of the way there.